# Google Auth0 having error 'Module '"@auth0/nextjs-auth0"' has no exported member 'UserProvider''

Tags: typescript, authentication, next.js, auth0

I'm using next.js and typescript, and would like to implement authentication using Google Auth0.

But I'm having this error. `Module '"@auth0/nextjs-auth0"' has no exported member 'UserProvider'.`
And I couldn't find it on Google. How can I solve it?

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { UserProvider } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </UserProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Answer (score 4):

Try importing from `"@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client"` instead.